# How to check each date if it's Thursday, if not print the following Thursday

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, conditional-statements

I have a column of dates in standard date time format. I have to check each date if it's Thursday or not and print if it's Thursday. If it's not then it have to print the following Thursday.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: please provide a sample df, desired output, and what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will print `It is Thursday` for every Thursday or print the date of the next `Thursday` for any given date.

```py
import datetime


def next_thursday(date):
    # Thursday is day 3 in Python (Monday = 0)
    days_ahead = 3 - date.weekday()
    if days_ahead == 0:
        print("It is Thursday")
    # if Thursday has already happened this week we need to add 7 days to the difference
    elif days_ahead < 0:
        days_ahead += 7
    # actually add the time delta using timedelta() 
    print(date + datetime.timedelta(days=days_ahead), "will be the next Thursday")


date = datetime.datetime.today()
next_thursday(date)
```

The following is a Python script that will apply abovementioned function to 20 generated random dates in a dataframe column.

```py
def random_date():
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    offset = random.randint(0, 100)
    return today + datetime.timedelta(days=offset)


dateCol = [random_date() for _ in range(20)]
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": dateCol})


df["date"].apply(next_thursday)
```